# Como fazer para ler um arquivo de texto e separá-lo em colunas, no C#?

Tags: c#

Como fazer para ler um arquivo de texto e separá-lo em colunas usando o método `split`, no C#?

Por exemplo:

```
-Thiago lemos, Brazil, profissao-
-Thiago lemos, Brazil, profissao-
-Thiago lemos, Brazil, profissao-
-Thiago lemos, Brazil, profissao-
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode ler cada linha e dividi-la em um array de strings, utilizando o método Split, como você falou acima, por um separador específico. No seu caso, a ",".
Assim, você pode pegar cada string dessa, pelo seu index e colocar em uma lista, assim você terá cada informação separada em sua respectiva lista... Mas, aconselho verificar se as linhas possuem a mesma quantidade de informação antes de fazer isso.

Algo como:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt");

IList coluna1 = new List<string>();

foreach (line in lines)
{
   var informacoes = line.Split(',');

   if (informacoes.Length == 3)
   {
      coluna1.add(informacoes[0]);
   }
}
```

Basicamente isso vai ler as suas linhas e colocar em um array, após isso vai fazer um laço passando por cada linha do seu array, e vai quebrar essa linha pela vírgula, adicionando em um novo array com essas strings quebradas. Caso o tamanho do array for igual à 3, baseado no exemplo que você trouxe acima, ele vai adicionar na lista que criamos, coluna1, o index 0 do seu array gerado pelo split da linha. Espero que não tenha ficado confuso e possa te ajudar.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer isso seguindo as seguintes etapas:

1 - Lê todas as linhas do arquivo e guarda em uma variável do tipo lista de strings (**string [] lines**);

2 - Faz um loop (pode ser utilizando o "for" mesmo) e percorre cada linha da sua lista de linhas (**lines**);

3 - Para cada linha do "for" você da um "split" utilizando o separador "," como parâmetro. Desta forma o split vai te gerar as suas colunas;

Abaixo um exemplo de código:

```
private void GetColumns()
    {
        //Lê todas as linhas do arquivo.
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("Exemplo.txt");
        
        //Percorre a lista de linhas do arquivo.
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            //Gera as colunas da linha atual com base no separador ","
            string[] sDados = lines[i].Split(',');
            
            //Checa se há dados para atribuir a coluna 1.
            if (sDados.Length > 0)
            {
                string sColuna1 = sDados[0];
            }

            //Checa se há dados para atribuir a coluna 2.
            if (sDados.Length > 1)
            {
                string sColuna2 = sDados[1];
            }

            //Checa se há dados para atribuir a coluna 3.
            if (sDados.Length > 2)
            {
                string sColuna3 = sDados[2];
            }
        }
    }
```